# What's the input of the render button?

Tags: rendering, objects, video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes, movie-clip-editor

So, recently I'm finding my way into blender video editing and compositing, however, I usually do these things in different projects because I don't know how the blender renderer works.

My question is, when I press "render", how do I know whether it's gonna render the video clip or the camera view, or both?
How should I place my camera to make the objects I model appear on the video clip?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you [uncheck sequencer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/post_process/panel.html#post-processing-panel), the sequencer strips are ignored. If you want to add your Scene to show up in the sequencer, add a *Scene* Strip.

Comment: I don't think I totally get it, could you be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

In Properties, on the Output tab (looks like a printer icon), if you go to Post Processing there are 2 checkboxes for Compositing and Sequencer - for the Compositor and Video Sequencer, respectively.